# Grails GORM/HQL - retrieve data from association

Tags: grails, hql, grails-orm

I have a Blog domain class, which has many messages:

```
class Blog {

    String description

    static hasMany = [messages : Message]
    static belongsTo = [owner : User]

    static constraints = {
        description blank: true, nullable: true
    }
}

class Message {

    String content
    String title
    User author

    Date dateCreated
    Date lastUpdated

    static hasMany = [comments : Comment]

    static constraints = {
        content blank: false
        author nullable: false
        title nullable: false, blank: false
    }

    static mapping = {
        content type: "text"
        sort dateCreated: 'desc'
    }
}
```

Message is used also in other places of the application, so association is unidirectional. How can I get 20 latest blog messages, ordered by creation date? By latest blog messages, I mean 20 latest messages which are associated with ANY blog.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class Blog {
    ...
    ...
    static hasMany [messages: BlogMessages]
    ...
    ...
}

class Message {
    ...
    // exactly like you have it
    ...
}

class BlogMessage extends Message {
    Blog blog
}
```

Then you can fetch like this...

```
BlogMessage.list([max:20])
```

Comment: I was thinking there might be other way than inheritance to achieve my goal.

Answer (score 0):

```
def latestMessages = Message.listOrderByDateCreated(max:20, order:"desc")
```

Comment: Thats fine, but there are other classes which are also associated with Message, and I want only those messages which are associated with blogs.